# filtering ParentalManyToManyField by query param in wagtail API

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-apiv2

I have a wagtail Page model like:

```
class PropertyPage(Page):
    ...
    categories = ParentalManyToManyField('property.PropertyCategory', blank=True)
```

Is it possible to have a query param to filter multiple values base on it?

```
/api/v2/pages/?type=property.PropertyPage&categories=1,2,3,...
```

right now I get this error:

```
"message": "query parameter is not an operation or a recognised field: categories"
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, my requirement was to filter a "ParentalManyToManyField" by multiple value and it can be done by query params in this format:

```
/api/v2/pages/?type=property.PropertyPage&categories=1&categories=2&...
```